# How to configure dnsmasq for wildcard subdomain in production server

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, dnsmasq

I am using dnsmasq to handle wildcard subdomains.

on my local machine, I have installed dnsmasq and added address=dev/127.0.0.1 in /etc/dnsmasq.conf file. It works fine on local after restarting the dnsmasq.

Now i am planning to make the code live on amazon ec2 instance with registered domain. I am unable to configure the dnsmasq there.

Can anyone help me?

I am using ngix.

Answer (score 0):

No need to run dnsmasq on your EC2 instance. 
Just configure your registered domain to use some DNS nameserver (usually, something like ns1.example.com, ns2.example.com). Then, on your DNS nameserver provider, you can usually configure out DNS records using some kind of web-based control panel. It's there where you create your DNS records and point them to your EC2 instance IP address.

In other words, I don't think you need to run dnsmasq in your EC2 instance, unless I'm getting your question wrong.